# Certain theorems assume 'any $a > 0$'; does this mean we can use $lim_{a \to 0}$ as well?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I am inexperienced in real analysis/more formal math, so I am wondering how to address this issue. I have seen certain theorems that are supposed to hold true for any $a > 0$, such as in Markov's Inequality and Epsilon-Delta proofs. I am wondering if this somehow implies that we can actually work with $a = 0$ in these cases. I'm sure there's some discretion needed, but I wanted to see how to address a few examples.

For example, (this relates to some methods I've seen in the epsilon-delta proof formulations), if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have that $|f(t) - c| \leq \varepsilon$, does this imply that $f(t) = c$? I could see this if we can take the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$, but not sure how to show that otherwise. I think the statement is true though (since I've seen it used before) so if this isn't the correct way to show it, I was wondering what else I can do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think that $\epsilon \to 0$ is same as $\epsilon = 0$?

Comment: No, I don't think that would be true generally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing your example: you can argue that $f(t) = c$ without using limits explicitly. Suppose $f(t) \neq c$. Then $|f(t) - c| = \delta > 0$. Since you can also choose $\epsilon = \frac{\delta}{2}$ you obtain
$$
\delta = |f(t) - c| \leq \frac{\delta}{2}
.
$$
which is only possible for $\delta = 0$.

Sometimes you can make similar arguments, if you already know that some property holds for every $a>0$ to obtain the property also for $a=0$.

Comment: So that is a sort of proof by contradiction? So we assume $f(t) \neq c$ and show that this leads to a contradiction that $\delta = 0$, so it must be that $f(t) =c$

Comment: @Slade exactly. However, you can also do the same steps without assuming $f(t) \neq c$ in the beginning. Then you will end up with $|f(t) - c| = 0$, which is equivalent to $f(t) = c$. So there is also a "positive" approach.

Comment: Ah okay. That covers a bunch of cases I have seen. Thanks a lot! An an aside, where did you learn how to figure this out? Is it from experience or is this a general notion that I could have found online if I knew some better search terms?

Comment: @Slade I guess you will find some similar argument in some textbooks. However, I studied mathematics and during my studies I had to do a lot of exercises, which taught me how to approach such problems. I don't think that you find an answer to this particular question by searching on the internet very easily, because it is an easy proof and most of the literature will assume that the reader has seen this already.